# How to generate web pages from CSV or other file?

Tags: csv

I have CSV file with 3 columns and some thousends rows, where each row means 1 product and each product has 3 information (1 column= 1 info , like name, short description 1,  short desription 2 ).
Is there any tool which will display all those information to my web page teplate or will automaticaly generate own page for each product from CSV, or from any other file type like XML or...
Thanks for any reply.

Comment: This tool you're looking for is your code. What don't you know? How to extract data from CSV or how to generate HTML? Be more precise, please. Try to do something. Internet is full of tutorials examples. Make some stupid implementation and ask question here if something doesn't work. Never ask on SO for a ready made solution! Good luck!

Comment: ...better to say, I am looking for any ready tool - any good site where I can download/buy it. I browsed Internet but nothing found, maybe i dont know which concrete right keywords should I type. I thought that anybody here could suggest me any....